# How to make a select menu with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I am trying to css a select menu with rounded corners but my fiddling has had no such luck, any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using the `select` element, then they're tricky to style since they're typically/mostly rendered by the OS/platform rather than the browser; so not all CSS is applied. And, cross-browser, the differences between what is, and isn't, applied becomes more difficult to predict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not expert in CSS but i think you 'll have to do something like that

```
#myDivID
{
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444347/how-to-make-select-dropdown-with-rounded-border?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

This rules make rounded corners, you should add your code so I can help you a bit more

```
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you want decent styling on a select element, you need to make your own mock element (out of plain old DIVs, lists, and such). To preserve form functionality, you can create a real hidden SELECT and use script to synchonize its state with the mock element the user is actually interacting with.

If you're a fan of jQuery, you can use jQuery UI to do much of this for you ([example](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html)).