# how to make select dropdown with rounded border?

Tags: html, css, select

i am using select tag for dropdown menu, using css i made select box to be rounded corner, by doing this drop down menu remains square, i also want to turn that rounded corner.

here is the live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ankurdhanuka/AwUHn/1/

**HTML**

```
<p class="formRight">
<span style="padding-right:100px">Lead Type: </span>

    <select id="leadType" class="box2" name="lead_type">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.formRight select {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #E8E8E8 inset;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Your Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These controls are handled by the OS so you may wish to consider creating your own drop-down list using CSS and JS.

Comment: @MatthewBaker how to create our own drop-down list?

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka You can create your own styled dropdown using HTML & JS. You can try jQuery plugins such as this: http://dev7studios.com/dropit/

Comment: Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927974/css-border-radius-for-the-drop-down-box-when-using-the-select-tag-not-the-sel

Comment: I guess you can not style a select options in a way you want!!! Try some alternatives, say an <ul> tag with <li> as the options and do style them... it will be pretty easy approach

Answer (score 21):

Please check the solution :

Live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/webx/2g5bydyo/

```css
.selectWrapper{
  border-radius:36px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#cccccc;
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
.selectBox{
  width:140px;
  height:40px;
  border:0px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectWrapper">
  <select class="selectBox">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd add width: initial instead width: 140px;

Comment: The dropdown  isn't radius.

Answer (score 12):

This is my solution.

**CSS**

```
.selectBox{border-radius:4px;border:1px solid #AAAAAA;}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectBox">
.............
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

Ankur, drop-down lists are controlled by the users operating system so full styling of these elements aren't possible.  To achieve the look you desire you may wish to consider developing, or using a [third-party custom drop-down list](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/).

From looking at your fiddle; [*Demo 5*](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index5.html) by Hugo Giraidel may provide you with with what you're looking for.

[image: Dropdown List]

Basically it uses HTML `<li>` elements and then using JS/jQuery it creates the drop-down list effect with a couple of basic transition effects.

Comment: Using custom select often ends with bad user experience. It is really hard to create good select box with good accessibility. This example also has issues. Demo and usage in production are different things...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this Stackoverflow post? 
[CSS - Border Radius for the drop down box when using the SELECT tag? Not the SELECT input ittself, the actual drop down box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927974/css-border-radius-for-the-drop-down-box-when-using-the-select-tag-not-the-sel)

Because what you are asking is not possible (or at leat not cross-browser compatible)

To make it work AND make it cross-browser compatible, you would have to create an dropdown/select with DIV elements (or any non form elements) and update their values with JS/jQuery to a hidden select. That way you can style the DIV the way you want without limitations.

This may help you out:
[JQuery Auto Complete substitute for Select Drop Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450490/jquery-auto-complete-substitute-for-select-drop-down/8450718#8450718)

Answer (score 0):

I don't now why, but it works when remove select default arrows

```
select {
  /* for Firefox */
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* for Chrome */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  /* For IE10 */
  display: none;
}

select {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `outline: none;` then add your border stuff... As a mater of a fact use `desired_parameter: none;` for every parameter you want to change then change it

```
select {
        outline: none;
        background-color: none;
        background-color: rgba(244,241,229,1.00);
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
        margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
        border: none;
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        border-radius: 4px;
}
```