# border-radius not working in MacOS/-webkit-

Tags: html, css

I am rounding some corners on a form inputs and found out that the border-radius doesn't work for `<select>`. It works on all the other input fields, but not on select dropdowns. I just noticed this when I grabbed my Macbook Pro and I don't remember seeing this problem while on my Windows machine. Is this a OSX/Browser issue?

I made a codepen to test it outside my environment, and sure enough! It doesn't work there either!

Have a look at the [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/BpeXXX)

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select User</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

CSS:

```
.form-control{
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -ms-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #bbb;
}
```

If it is a Mac OS/Browser combo issue, is there a workaround to this?

UPDATE:

Safari is fine, but not Chrome or Safari

Comment: I think you might need to wrap it.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444347/how-to-make-select-dropdown-with-rounded-border  Specifically the third answer which links to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/webx/2g5bydyo/

Comment: Select element is very hard to style up, specially aiming every platform/browser. Some people prefer to build up a dropdown using another markup, and handle it with JS to sync to a traditional form control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3pydev/rqcd522m/) using your code and the third answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444347/how-to-make-select-dropdown-with-rounded-border):

```
<div class="form-control">
  <div class="form-control rounded">
    <select class="form-select">
        <option value="">Select User</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <input type="text" class="rounded">
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.form-control {
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.form-select {
  border:0px;
  outline:none;
}

.rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -ms-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Great job j3py! After some more styling, it worked out perfectly. Great workaround.