# how to change the css of the drop down list?

Tags: html, css

I have used select tag for a drop down as mentioned below.

```
<select id="identifier" [(ngModel)]="stagePropertyModel.stageIdentifier" 
                    (ngModelChange)="signalChanged($event)"
                     class="propClass">
                <option *ngFor="let val of identifers" [ngValue]="val">
                    {{val}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

how do we change the drop down list box's corner to curved with border-radius 4px.

Comment: Selects are styled by the OS, not by CSS. You'll need to fake the behaviour in order to provide styling but this will probably reduce UX on some devices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444347/how-to-make-select-dropdown-with-rounded-border

Comment: This is not the exact same question. In the previous questions, it's been answered how to curve the borders of the drop down field box not the drop down list box, When you click on the drop down field, it expands with the options, I want to change the borders of the box which opens on expanding drop down field.